# Return all row indices of non-NA values numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with a lot of NaN values and in some rows non-NA values.

Now, I want to get all indices of the rows that have a non-NA value (i.e. a numeric values) and want to extract the values for these specific row indices from a different numpy array. So we have:

Y_test, a np array  of length 698 with on some rows numeric values

```
Y_test
array([ nan,  13.,  nan,  10.,  nan])
```

Y_pred, a np array  of length 698 with numeric values on each row

```
Y_pred
array([ 0.96,  0.57,  0.33,  0.43,  0.83])
```

I want to only extract the numeric values of np_array2 on the indices of the rows with numeric values in np_array1.

For example:

```
array([ 0.57, 0.43])
```

I am doing this to calculate the error between the non-NA rows from Y_test and the corresponding rows of Y_pred.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post sample arrays so that users can demonstrate solutions to your problem.

Comment: Just create a mask `mask = ~np.isnan(array_with_nans)` and index your arrays with that `array_with_nans[mask]`, `array_without_nans[mask]`. If you definitely need the indices: `np.flatnonzero(mask)`. If you also want to exclude `+/-inf` use `mask = np.isfinite(array_with_nans)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to find the indices where an array is `nan` and then just use the inverse.

```
np.isnan(Y_test)
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
Y_pred[~np.isnan(Y_test)]
array([ 0.57,  0.43])
```

**EDIT**

Per further input I understand that your two arrays have different sizes. In that case you can use [`flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) as @PaulPanzer pointed out.

```
np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(Y_test))
array([1, 3])
Y_pred[np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(Y_test))]
```